# How to start Google Chrome Browser in Incognito mode with Proxy settings using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I would like to launch Google Chrome Browser on my MacBook in incognito mode with proxy IP and port assigned using AppleScript or Automator.

I tried using following AppleScript code but not working.

```
tell application “Google Chrome”

activate

make new window with properties {mode:”incognito”, proxy:”192.168.1.10:4848″}

end tell
```

```
tell application “Google Chrome”

activate

make new window with properties {mode:”incognito”, proxy:”192.168.1.10:4848″}

end tell
```